# Existence of maximum of one set.

Tags: calculus, analysis

I have a question, if $A$ is a set of parameters, when can I say that $\text{max} {\{N_{\lambda}\in\mathbb{N}:\lambda \in A}\} $ exists?

It is clear that said maximum exists for finite $ A $, but if the $ N_ {\lambda}$ are very ugly, is it a necessary and sufficient condition that $ A $ be finite?

Comment: It is sufficient, but it is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, how to think of an example?

Comment: I’m sorry: I misread the problem and didn’t realize that all of the $N_\lambda$ were natural numbers. In that case yes, the set has a maximum iff it is finite.